# sql query to bring last letter in a string to first letter position

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table name called 'Supervisor' from a table JobData in a MSSQL database. In this 'Supervisor' column the records are of the format "SPARKSL", "ADITYAG", "KENTONS", "DRISCOLLJ" and so on. I want to convert these records to lower case and bring the last letter to first letter.For example "SPARKSL" should be changed to the format "lsparks", "gaditya", "skentons" and so on and this format should be applied to all the remaining records.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. What part(s) of this do you need help with? What have you tried?

Comment: KENTONS -> skentons? Shouldn't it be skenton?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it should appear like last letter at the first i.e., gaditya, lsparks, skenton and so on

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to clarify your problem description and if possible add some minimal code. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
WITH Demo AS
(
  SELECT X FROM (VALUES ('SPARKSL'),('ADITYAG'),('KENTONS')) T(X)
)
SELECT *, LOWER(SUBSTRING(X, LEN(X),1)+SUBSTRING(X,1,LEN(X)-1))
FROM Demo
```

Answer (score 1):

Just building off of Tim's answers (all three answers look fine)...

Yes - you will get an error is you pass it a blank or whitespace (one or more spaces only) because `LEN(' ') = 0`. 0-1 = -1. `LEFT(<something>,-1)` is not valid. To fix that you would change Tim's logic for `new_sup` to look like this:

```
ISNULL(LOWER(LEFT(Supervisor, NULLIF(LEN(Supervisor),0) - 1)),'') AS new_sup
```

The complete, updated solution would look like this:

```
DECLARE @yourtable TABLE (Supervisor VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @yourtable(Supervisor)
VALUES ('SPARKSL'),('ADITYAG'),('KENTONS'),('DRISCOLLJ'),(' '),('');

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        LOWER(RIGHT(Supervisor, 1)) +
        ISNULL(LOWER(LEFT(Supervisor, NULLIF(LEN(Supervisor),0) - 1)),'') AS new_sup
    FROM @yourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this option:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        LOWER(RIGHT(Supervisor, 1)) +
        LOWER(LEFT(Supervisor, LEN(Supervisor) - 1)) AS new_sup
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT *
FROM cte;
```

[image]

### Demo

If you instead want to actually *update* your supervisor column, then you may also use the above CTE:

```
UPDATE cte
SET Supervisor = new_sup;
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. But, getting an error "invalid length parameter passed on to left or substring function. Unfortunately, it isn't working :(

Comment: @adityagoud Well, it _is_ working, at least with the sample data you provided.  Which means that you must have some _other_ data which is causing this problem.  Do you have any null or short values (e.g. 1-3 characters) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize the `LOWER`, `RIGHT`, `SUBSTRING` AND `LEN` commands. ie;

```
 UPDATE [Supervisor] SET [Supervisor] = LOWER(RIGHT([Supervisor], 1) + SUBSTRING([Supervisor],1, (LEN([Supervisor])-1)))
```