# SQL QUERY to bring last letter in a string to first letter position using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called `Supervisor` from a table `JobData` in a SQL Server database. In this `Supervisor` column the records are of the format below.

```
DANNYL
ADITYAG
SAMMYS
BOBBYJ
```

I want to convert these records to lower case and bring the last letter to first letter. For example, `DANNYL` should be changed to the format `ldanny` and this format should be applied to all the remaining records.

Can anyone help me out with a SQL query for this?

Comment: _Column_, not field. _Rows_, not records.

Comment: Since this looks like they are FirstName and first initial of the last name I would suggest that what you really should be doing is separating these into two columns. Then you can create a computed column to put them together in whatever format you want. If you start with properly normalized data (this isn't because it violates 1NF) this kind of thing is easy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql query to bring last letter in a string to first letter position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277524/sql-query-to-bring-last-letter-in-a-string-to-first-letter-position)

Comment: @SMor - nice catch! that's not a possible duplicate - **it is a duplicate**. But if I compare the answers they are good and working but the answers here are very different and working too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following solution using `LEFT` and `RIGHT` to get the parts of the name. By using [`LOWER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lower-transact-sql) you can convert the upper case characters to lower case:

```
SELECT LOWER(RIGHT(Supervisor, 1) + LEFT(Supervisor, LEN(Supervisor) - 1)) 
FROM JobData
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(Supervisor)) <> ''

-- or using ABS on the length - 1 so the WHERE isn't needed.
SELECT LOWER(RIGHT(Supervisor, 1) + LEFT(Supervisor, ABS(LEN(Supervisor) - 1))) 
FROM JobData
```

Since it looks like the column `Supervisor` contains empty values you can also use the following solution without calculation and not failing on the empty values:

```
SELECT LOWER(RIGHT(Supervisor, 1) + REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Supervisor), 2, LEN(Supervisor))))
FROM JobData
```

... and another possibility using [`STUFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql):

```
SELECT LOWER(LEFT(STUFF(Supervisor, 1, 0, RIGHT(Supervisor, 1)), LEN(Supervisor)))
FROM JobData
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a7b28387d840d94b0a4934baa672e479)

Comment: I'm getting an error while coversion of varchar to integer. The field I'm using for conversion is of type varchar, So, converison of varchar to integer is failing.

Comment: Select lower(right(Supervisor, 1) + left(Supervisor, LEN(Supervisor)))
From JobData

This is the sql statement I've used and it works.
Thanks for your support

Comment: your query works fine on the demo with provided values. Your provided query doesn't work as described. You have to use `LEN - 1` - you get jbobbyj instead of jbobby

Comment: Yes, I got the same result. dannyl resulted to ldannyl. Which I don't want

Comment: Yes because you are missing the `-1` after the length. - `Select lower(right(Supervisor, 1) + left(Supervisor, LEN(Supervisor)-1)) From JobData`

Comment: If I use it, I'm getting an error "Invalid length parameter passed to the left or substring function"
How do i avoid this?

Comment: You have to filter the empty Supervisor columns. See the update and demo.

Answer (score 1):

there is probably a better way do to that , but here is my proposition.

```
SELECT lower(left(right('DANYL',1)+'DANYL',len('DANYL')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `SUBSTRING` you can get the expected result:

```
SELECT LOWER(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Supervisor, LEN(Supervisor), 1), SUBSTRING(Supervisor, 0, LEN(Supervisor))))
FROM JobData
```

Demo with the given sample data:

```
DECLARE @JobData TABLE (Supervisor VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @JobData (Supervisor) VALUES
('DANNYL'), ('ADITYAG'), ('SAMMYS'), ('BOBBYJ');

SELECT LOWER(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Supervisor, LEN(Supervisor), 1), SUBSTRING(Supervisor, 0, LEN(Supervisor)))) AS Supervisor
FROM @JobData
```

Output:

```
ldanny
gaditya
ssammy
jbobby
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? :

```
SELECT
LOWER(CONCAT(SUBSTRING([Supervisor], LEN([Supervisor]), 1),SUBSTRING([Supervisor], 1, ABS(LEN([Supervisor])-1))))
FROM TABLE
```